# pip install hypothesis[pandas] says hypothesis3.82.1 does not provide the extra 'pandas'

Tags: python-hypothesis

When I ran pip install hypothesis[pandas] I got the following:

`Collecting hypothesis[pandas]
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/58/222aafec5064d12c2b6123c69e512933b1e82a55ce49015371089d216f89/hypothesis-3.82.1-py3-none-any.whl
  hypothesis 3.82.1 does not provide the extra 'pandas'`

pip install hypothesis[django] seemed to work and hypothesis.extra has django but not pandas. Any idea what is going on with the pip install for pandas and numpy extras?

Answer (score 1):

fixed my problem with 

`pip install hypothesis[all]`

and also realizing that hypothesis.extra tab completion only showed django, and that pandas and numpy extras seem to need to be imported explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

*Update: [Hypothesis 3.82.2](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#v3-82-2) added the metadata to support `pip install hypothesis[pandas]`.*

---

Looks like we simply haven't added it to the setuptools metadata - now tracking via [issue 1671](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/1671) for any first-time contributor who would like to fix it :)

FYI this won't actually add any dependencies though; if you have both Hypothesis and Pandas>0.19 installed the extra will just work!